# Django exception: decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: python, django

I have strange behavor in code.

My model is:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ....
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Цена товара", verbose_name="Цена")
    # price = models.IntegerField(help_text="Цена товара", verbose_name="Цена")
```

When I try filter object:

```
class ProductBuyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, item_uuid: str, format=None):
        product = Item.objects.all().filter(uuid__exact=uuid.UUID(item_uuid))[0]
        ...
```

I get an exception

```
File "/home/lev/python_projects/taste_case_stripe/stripe_app/views.py", line 14, in get
    product = Item.objects.all().filter(uuid__exact=uuid.UUID(item_uuid))[0]
  File "/home/lev/python_projects/taste_case_stripe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 445, in __getitem__
    qs._fetch_all()
  File "/home/lev/python_projects/taste_case_stripe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/lev/python_projects/taste_case_stripe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 117, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/lev/python_projects/taste_case_stripe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1333, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/lev/python_projects/taste_case_stripe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 344, in converter
    return create_decimal(value).quantize(
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

**...decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]**

but when I change type field to **Int**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ....
    price = models.IntegerField(help_text="Цена товара", verbose_name="Цена")
```

everthing is OK. As I guess the problem is decimal field. But what is wrong with it...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Model
# Create your models here.

class DecimalModel(Model):
    geeks_field = models.DecimalField(
                     max_digits = 5,
                     decimal_places = 2)
```

in view:

```
from geeks.models import DecimalModel

# importing datetime module
import decimal

# creating an instance of 
# datetime.date
d = decimal.Decimal(9.53)

# creating an instance of 
# DecimalModel
my_object = DecimalModel.objects.create(geeks_field = d)
my_object.save()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how it helps me. I have problem with getting object, not creating

Comment: Item(uuid=uuid.uuid4(), name="Товар 1", description="Описание", price=99.00).save() works well

Comment: try this:    product = Item.object.get(uuid__exact=uuid.UUID(item_uuid))
print(product)

Comment: the same problem {InvalidOperation}[<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some problem with data in your database. Can you delete all data from your `Item` table? Problem should go away after this. As i see you use SQLight so you can copy db file as backup and try `Item` table clean to diagnose the source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#decimal-handling). I changed DB to MySQL. And did the same query to MySQL storage. In this case the issue is disappeared.